# AJAX error, don't know what's wrong (Google Maps API, JQuery, Django)

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I'm trying to pass address information from JS to Django `views.py`.

Currently, I have the JS fill in a hidden form that is POST'ed to Django, but this method is hacky and vulnerable to users tampering with the form data in Inspector (I'd like the data to be exactly as Google API says it is).

Here is the JS that gives the error:

```
    var objAddress = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
        var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
        console.log(addressType)
        if (componentForm[addressType]) {
            var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
            console.log(val)
            objAddress[addressType] = val;
        }
    }
    console.log(objAddress);
    var address = JSON.stringify(objAddress);
    console.log(address);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/place/new/',
        data: {
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
            address: address
        },
        success: function (response, textStatus, error) {
            console.log('SUCCESS');
        },
        error: function (request, textStatus, error) {
            console.log(error);
            console.log(textStatus);
        }
    });
```

On Django's side, it does not receive a POST at all. The `address` is correct. I've tried variations such as sending a string in `data` and nothing works. I'm inexperienced with JQuery, and I don't know where else to look right now.

`views.py`:

```
def placenew(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    address = request.POST.get('address')
    response_data = {} #what does this do?
    print (address)
    return render(request, 'app/placenew.html', {'gkey':gkey})
else:
    print ("not POST")
    return render(request, 'app/placenew.html', {'gkey':gkey})
```

`urls.py`

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include
from app.forms import BootstrapAuthenticationForm
from rest_framework import routers #REST
from app import views #REST
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^places/??$', 'app.views.places', name='places'),
    url(r'^place/(?P<placeid>[0-9]+)/??$', 'app.views.place', name='place'),
    url(r'^place/new/??$', 'app.views.placenew', name='placenew'),
)
```

Comment: It just prints out from the `console.log('error')`. On Django side, I have a `if request.method == 'POST':` and `else:
        print ("not POST")` Updating OP with `views.py`

Comment: What is the actual error you get? (log the `error` var might help),

Comment: `console.log(error)` gives `FORBIDDEN`

Comment: Posted `urls.py` to OP

Comment: Two things to try (to diagnose)... 1.  Use the correct django url syntax instead of `/place/new/ - {% url 'placenew' %}` and 2. add the `@csrf_exempt` decorator to your view to see if it is a csrf issue as I suspected (Note the `exempt` is *not* a final solution)

Comment: `@csrf_exempt` worked, SUCCESS log and the correct information is printed from Django. If I use `{% url 'placenew' %}` it results in error `'initialize' is undefined`

Comment: Ok, so the token is the issue then, (the url may need any namespace included `ns:placenew` and should be surrounded by quotes still.) Its possible your current token got cached somehow invalidating it, but other than the `beforeSend` I'm not sure what is wrong here. you could try the doc's `getCookie` method but I don't always like using that

Comment: Cached as in browser cache? I could try clearing that if there's a chance that may be the culprit, could you paste the `beforeSend` snippet again?

Comment: I've undeleted my answer, and yes a previous token could be getting held somewhere

Comment: Good luck finding the solution, if you do find it, feel free to answer your own question. it may help future users :)